# Create pre-rewritten(?) URL using an SQL ID

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So, I've just installed a code pasting utility on my website (like PasteBin basically, but using the open source PASTE script).
At the moment, a paste will be saved in the SQL database, with an integer ID.
The paste utilities directory is http://example.com/paste, and pastes can be found at http://example.com/paste/12345.

What I'd like to do, is create an htaccess rule so that when the user clicks on http://example.com/12345, they will be taken to http://example.com/paste/12345.

I've looked around at other questions, but none seem to ask (or solve) the same sort of question. But I could have looked in the wrong place, and someone will have a link to an answer within minutes of me posting. That would be equally great, but I'd prefer a more tailored solution, if possible.

NOTE: If anyone just wants to change the clickable link from http://example.com/paste/12345 (for example) to http://example.com/p/12345 without changing the actual subfolder name, check out my comment in the Accepted Answer. Otherwise, Dope Monk's solution will work fine for my initial problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ... Google is for tutorials ... SO is for specific problems.

Comment: Thank you for including that URL - put a whole new perspective on asking questions! Anyway, I did follow a tutorial, but having looked at what @Dope Monk put (which is the same as I tried to do), I've realised the problem was a typo... EDIT: Dope's didn't work out of the box, actually. Managed to sort it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a simple rule in your .htaccess using mod_rewrite. However, you must ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled when you use this rule

Add this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/$ /paste/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I actually changed the way I wanted to do it, so that it would go to `[url]/paste/12345` if the URL was`[url]/p/12345` (having the ID in the root directory seems a bit dogdey/messy to me). I put: `RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)/$ /paste/$1 [NC,L]` so that it would do `[url]/p/12345`, but it gave a 404.
I played around with the settings (with my very limited knowledge and Google) and managed to get it working using `RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]*)$ /paste/$1 [L]`. I modified a URL shortener rule, and merged the changes.
Thanks for the push in the right direction though!